# Nested RSpec Tests

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, nested

I am following Michael Hartl's tutorial and came across this following codes that I am having trouble comprehending.

```
  describe "index" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before(:each) do
      sign_in user
      visit users_path
    end

    it { should have_title('All users') }
    it { should have_content('All users') }

    describe "pagination" do

      before(:all) { 30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } }
      after(:all)  { User.delete_all }

      it { should have_selector('div.pagination') }

      it "should list each user" do
        User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
          expect(page).to have_selector('li', text: user.name)
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

My question is: 
is this a NESTED TEST where the test block of Pagination runs inside Index Test block? in other words, the sequence of testing flow:

1. before(:each) outer block of signing in user and visiting user path is executed
2. then the inner block of 30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user) is executed
3. then the inner block of it { should have_selector('div.pagination') } is executed
4. then the inner block of  expect(page).to have_selector('li', text: user.name) is executed

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here's the flow for the above test:

The `before(:each)` block is executed before each of the following:

```
it { should have_title('All users') }
it { should have_content('All users') }
```

Then, the `before(:each)` is executed again, followed by the `describe block`, which executes:

```
before(:all) { 30.times { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } }

it { should have_selector('div.pagination') }

it "should list each user" do
  User.paginate(page: 1).each do |user|
    expect(page).to have_selector('li', text: user.name)
  end
end
```

Finally, `after(:all)  { User.delete_all }` is executed.

I hope this helps explain the flow.

Comment: It would seem to make more sense if the Pagination block is not nested but rather separated from Index block. In other words, write a independent sign-in user and visit-user block for the Pagination test.

Comment: Why? You'd only have pagination if you're visiting the `index` and you have enough users to paginate...